# Error al querer guardar campo fecha con procedimiento almacenado con valores de tablas desde c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, stored-procedure

tengo un procedimiento almacenado en el cual utilizao table type lstconcepto que representa la tabla concepto, esto va asi guardo en la tabla venta y el id de esta tabla se guarda en la tabla concepto como llave foranea, capturo el id lo guardo en una variable llamada @idVenta
todo este proceso lo hace bien

ire por paso para que me puedan entender

```
USE [MaestroDetalleProcedimiento]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGuardaVenta]
    @cliente varchar(100),
    @lstConceptos Detail READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    declare @idVenta int
    
    insert into venta(cliente,fecha) values( @cliente,GETDATE())

    set @idVenta = @@IDENTITY

    insert into concepto(id_venta,nombre,cantidad,precio,fechas)
    select @idVenta,nombre,cantidad,precio,fechas from @lstConceptos
END
```

aqui creo table type Detail

```
create type Detail AS TABLE(
    Id int,
    Nombre varchar(50),
    Cantidad int,
    Precio decimal(18, 2),
    Fechas datetime
    primary key (Id)
    )
```

en la tabla concepto ya esta creado el campo fechas como datetime de igual forma en el Detial.
Ahora para ejecutarlo lo hago de la siguiente forma solo para saber que esta corriendo bien

```
declare @lstConceptos Detail
insert into @lstConceptos(Id,
    Cantidad,
    Nombre,
    Precio,
    Fechas)
values (1,1,'carlos',1,'1-1-2021')
exec dbo.spGuardaVenta 'picapiedra',@lstConceptos 
select * from venta
select * from concepto
```

si en el Detail yo agrego un campo tipo entero, varchar o decimal al ejecutarlo en c# guarda la informacion en al base de datos (previamente agrege esos campos ala tabla concepto) PERO si le agrego el campo fecha  solo recibo este mensaje

```
'System.Exception' en CapaDatos.dll
System.Exception: Error: ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.
Los datos para el parámetro con valores de tabla '@lstConceptos' no se ajustan al tipo de tabla del parámetro. El error de SQL Server es: 241, estado: 1
```

en c# tengo lo siguiente en el formulario el datepicker ya le pase lo siguiente pero aun asi sigue mandano el mismo mensaje y no guardo nada ya que tengo una transaccion

```
// DateTime Fechas = txtfecha.Value.Date;
// DateTime Fechas = txtfecha.Value;
//DateTime Fechas = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfecha.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

este es el form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using CapaDatos;

namespace Presentacion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ConceptoModelo xConceptoModelo= new ConceptoModelo();
        
      
    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xlistar();
        }
        public void xlistar()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = xConceptoModelo.cdo_listarConcepto();
        }

        private void btnagregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
            string Cantidad = txtCantidad.Text;
            string Precio = txtPrecio.Text;
            string Fechas = txtfecha.Text;

           // DateTime Fechas = txtfecha.Value.Date;
            // DateTime Fechas = txtfecha.Value;
            //DateTime Fechas = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfecha.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
            

            dgvConceptos.Rows.Add(new object[]{
                    Cantidad,Nombre,Precio,Fechas,"Eliminar"
                });

            txtCantidad.Text = "";
            txtNombre.Text = "";
            txtPrecio.Text = "";
            txtCantidad.Focus();
            Console.WriteLine(dgvConceptos);
        }

     
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Concepto> lst = new List<Concepto>();

                //llenado de elementos detalles
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvConceptos.Rows)
                {
                    Concepto oConcepto = new Concepto();
                    oConcepto.Nombre = dr.Cells["nombre"].Value.ToString();
                    oConcepto.Cantidad = int.Parse(dr.Cells["cantidad"].Value.ToString());
                    oConcepto.Precio = decimal.Parse(dr.Cells["precio"].Value.ToString());
                    oConcepto.Fechas = DateTime.Parse(dr.Cells["fechas"].Value.ToString());

                    lst.Add(oConcepto);
                    Console.WriteLine(lst);
                }

                VentaDB oVenta = new VentaDB();
                oVenta.Add(txtCliente.Text, lst);

                MessageBox.Show("Venta realizada");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }

        private void dgvConceptos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex != dgvConceptos.Columns["Op"].Index)
                return;

            dgvConceptos.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }

    }
}
```

en la capadatos
clase ventadb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace CapaDatos
{
   public class VentaDB
    {
       private string connectionString = "Data Source=SAMSUNGA50; Initial Catalog=MaestroDetalleProcedimiento; Integrated Security=True";


       public void Add(string Cliente,  List<Concepto> lst)
       {
           var dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Columns.Add("Id");
           dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
           dt.Columns.Add("Cantidad");
           dt.Columns.Add("Precio");
           dt.Columns.Add("Fechas");

           int i = 1;
           foreach (var oElement in lst)
           {
               dt.Rows.Add(i,
                   oElement.Nombre, 
                   oElement.Cantidad,
                   oElement.Precio,
                  oElement.Fechas
                   );
               i++;
           }

           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
               connection.Open();
               using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
               {
                   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spGuardaVenta", connection);
                   command.Connection = connection;
                   command.Transaction = transaction;
                   var parametroLista = new SqlParameter("@lstConceptos", SqlDbType.Structured);
                   parametroLista.TypeName = "dbo.Detail";
                   parametroLista.Value = dt;
                   try
                   {
                       command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                       command.Parameters.Add(parametroLista);
                       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", Cliente);
                    
                       

                       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       transaction.Commit();
                       connection.Close();
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       transaction.Rollback();
                       throw new Exception("Error:", ex);
                       
                   }
               }

           }
       }
      
    }
}
```

la clase concepto

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using CapaDatos;

namespace CapaDatos
{
    
    public class Concepto
    {
        private int id;
        private string nombre;
        private int cantidad;        
        private decimal precio;
        private DateTime fechas;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public string Nombre
        {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }

        public decimal Precio
        {
            get { return precio; }
            set { precio = value; }
        }

        public int Cantidad
        {
            get { return cantidad; }
            set { cantidad = value; }
        }

        public DateTime Fechas
        {
            get { return fechas; }
            set { fechas = value; }
        }

}}
```

la verdad no veo que error estoy cometiendo, talves me echan otraves una mano en el codigo, les agradezco.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar o hacer referencia a una fecha en SQL es necesario hacerlo mediante el formato definido en la norma [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). En el caso de fecha (sin hora) corresponde con año-mes-día, en la notación habitual yyyy-MM-dd, por lo que la sentencia de inserción donde interviene la fecha debería ser

```
declare @lstConceptos Detail
insert into @lstConceptos(Id,
    Cantidad,
    Nombre,
    Precio,
    Fechas)
values (1,1,'carlos',1,'2021-01-01')
```

Comment: Saludos @Roger, con ese query no tengo ningun problema al hacer pruebas si quito elcampo Fechas y agrego otro ya sea entero, decimal cuando mando a guardar desde c# lo hace, solamente es con el campo fecha que me muestra el error que mencione.

Answer (score 0):

ademas de ponerle el formato a los textbox en el formulario tenia que hacerlo en la clase ventabd pero de esta manera.  Espero les ayude en sus proyectos.

```
//
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id",typeof(Int32)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nombre", typeof(string)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cantidad", typeof(Int32)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Precio", typeof(Int32)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fechas", typeof(DateTime)));
```